# Prove that $\phi$ surjective and open as well as closed map.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Let $\phi:\mathbf{C}^{3}\rightarrow \mathbf{C}^{3}$ be the map $(x,y,z)\mapsto (x+y+z,xy+yz+zx,xyz)$. Prove that $\phi$ surjective and open as well as closed map.

**My Attempt**: Surjectivity follows from Vieta's formula's. But what about open and closed?. is it true that component functions are open (closed) if and only if original function open (closed)?.  is there any sequential criteria for open and closed map like continuous map?. What are techniques are frequently useful to show a map is open (closed)?.

Comment: You can't check if a map is open by checking if each component is open: $(x, y, z) \mapsto (x, x, x)$.

Answer (score 1):

There are sequential criteria to show that $\phi$ is closed.

A subset $A \subset \mathbb C^3$ is closed iff limits of convergent (in $\mathbb C^3$!) sequences  $(s_n)$ with $s_n \in A$ belong to $A$.

So let $A \subset \mathbb C^3$ be closed and $(s_n)$ be a sequence in $\phi(A)$ with limit $s \in \mathbb C^3$. We have to show $s \in \phi(A)$.

Write $s_n = (a_n, b_n,c_n)$. We know that $s_n = \phi(s'_n)$ with $s'_n = (a'_n,b'_n,c'_n)$, where $a'_n,b'_n,c'_n$ are the roots of the polynomial $p_n(z) = z^3 - a_nz^2 + b_nz - c_n$. It is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots) that the absolute values of these roots are $\le r_n := 1 + \lvert a_n \rvert + \lvert b_n \rvert + \lvert c_n \rvert$.

Since $s_n \to s$, the sequence $(s_n)$ is bounded, thus the sequence $(r_n)$ is bounded and so is $(s'_n)$. Therefore $(s'_n)$ has a  convergent subsequence $(s'_{n_k})$. Let $s'$ be its limit. Since all $s'_{n_k} \in A$,  we conclude $s' \in A$ and by continuity of $\phi$ we get $s = \lim_{k \to \infty} s_{n_k} = \lim_{k \to \infty} \phi(s'_{n_k})  = \phi(s') \in \phi(A)$.

I am not aware of a "sequential" proof that $\phi$ is open. Here is my suggestion.

Since $\phi$ is a closed continuous surjection, it is a quotient map. To show that $\phi(U)$ is open if $U$ is open, it therefore suffices to show that $\phi^{-1}(\phi(U))$ is open.

The symmetric group $S_3$ acts on $\mathbb C^3$ by permutation of the coordinates. For $\sigma \in S_3$ we get the map

$$t_\sigma : \mathbb C^3 \to \mathbb C^3, t_\sigma(z_1,z_2,z_3) = (z_{\sigma(1)}, z_{\sigma(2)}, z_{\sigma(3)}) .$$
These maps are homeomorphisms (with inverse $t_\sigma^{-1} = t_{\sigma^{-1}}$). We have $\phi(z_1,z_2,z_3) = \phi(w_1,w_2,w_3)$
if and only if $(w_1,w_2,w_3) = t_\sigma(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ for some $\sigma \in S_3$. This implies
$$\phi^{-1}(\phi(U)) =  \bigcup_{\sigma \in S_3} t_\sigma(U) .$$

Hence $\phi^{-1}(\phi(U))$ is open if $U$ is open.

Answer (score -1):

The first aim is to prove that if $U$ is an open set, $\phi(U)$ is open.

Roughly speaking, look at a small enough open neighbourhood of $\phi(u)$, where $u\in U$,

and try to show that every point in such a neighbourhood is the image of some point so close to $u$ that it is guaranteed to be in $U$.

For this purpose, ask yourself how much the roots of a monic cubic equation will change if you make tiny changes to the coefficients. (By the way, 'monic' means that the leading coefficient is $1$.)

If you start with an equation $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$, how far will the roots go if you change each coefficient by no more than $\epsilon$?

$\\$

The second aim is to prove that if $T$ is a closed set, $\phi(T)$ is closed.

Suppose that the sequence $\phi(t_i)$ converges to $p$. Note that $p$ has only a finite number of pre-images under $\phi$.

Again, using the same point that I made above concerning a small change to the coefficients and a consequent small change to the roots,

you can show that there must be a subsequence of $t_i$ converging to one of the pre-images of $p$.